# C++ removing elements from random function

Tags: c++, random, element

I want to create a `2D array a[5][5]` that  there are no 2 same numbers in it and  none of element is  0 (elements are generated by function `random(70)`) so i was wondering how to remove zero and  to make sure that there are no 2 same numbers ?

Comment: `random(69) + 1` ?

Comment: @Lol4t0 srand(time(0))    rand(70)   gives numbers from 0-69 and i do not want to use 0...

Comment: @user3127589 well __ADD 1__ to the generated numbers. That's what Lol4t0 suggested. Read the comment once more.

Comment: @PawełStawarz lol didnt realize what he says...

Comment: @PawełStawarz that still leaves problem with same numbers...

Comment: Every time you get a new rand number scan the already filled part of your array, and if the number is there, continue calling `rand` and testing until the number is unique - then store it in the array and proceed with the next positin (until the array if full).

Answer (score 2):

You can use something as the following

```
const size_t N = 5;
int a[N][N];

std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( 0 ) );

int *p = reinterpret_cast<int *>( a );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N * N; i++ ) 
{
   int x;

   while ( !( x = std::rand() % 70 ) || std::find( p, p + i, x ) != p + i ) {}
   p[i] = x;
}
```

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>


int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 5; 
    int a[N][N];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( 0 ) );

    int *p = reinterpret_cast<int *>( a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N * N; i++ )
    {
        int x;

        while ( !( x = std::rand() % 70 ) || std::find( p, p + i, x ) != p + i );

        p[i] = x;
    }   

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A sample output is

```
66 23 32 6 18 
8 31 55 10 43 
39 2 28 4 56 
5 58 47 46 68 
59 25 26 9 50
```

This approach does not require additional memory.

The other approach is to use `std::bitset`. For example

```
const size_t N = 5; 
int a[N][N];

std::bitset<70> b;
b.set( 0 );


std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( 0 ) );


for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
    {
        int x;

        while ( ( x = std::rand() % 70, b[x] ) );
        //or
        //while ( b[x = std::rand() % 70] );

        b.set( x );
        a[i][j] = x;
   }
}
```